# Merge [value-type] into [value-types]?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

I found on SO that [value-type](/questions/tagged/value-type) (92) is more popular than [value-types](/questions/tagged/value-types) (36).

But as far as I could see, plural form is preferred.

So maybe merge one into another?

Comment: I also merged [valuetypes].

Comment: @Robert, Could you also merge [tag:reference-type] and [tag:reference-types]?

Comment: @Robert, while on the path to commandeering the OP's intent, how about [tag:reference]->[tag:references] and [tag:preference]->[tag:preferences]?  Though there is a slightly awkward semantic difference between *preference* as in tastes/desires and *preferences* as user specific configuration, but the questions tagged [tag:preference] appear mean [tag:preferences] by and large

Comment: @M.T: For those tags, see here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97518/common-words-being-co-opted-for-specific-tag-usage

Comment: Some day, when my account is all big and grown up, I'll be able to propose these myself...  Thanks for doing most of the work @Robert!

Comment: @Robert: Thank you! Could you please post an answer to accept it

Comment: The [status-completed] tag should suffice.

Comment: @RobertHarvey any two similar merging can be told to the moderator?